# Create a table from a CSV file with headers

Tags: mysql, csv, import, bulk

I'm seeking to find a way to generate a new MySQL table solely based on the contents of a specified CSV. The CSV files I'll be using have the following properties;

- "|" delimited.
- First row specifies the column names (headers), also "|" delimited.
- Column names & order are not fixed.
- The number of columns is not fixed.
- Files are of a large size (1 mil rows / 50 columns).

In Excel this is all rather simple, however with MySQL it does not appear to be (no luck with Google). Any suggestions on what I should be looking at?

Answer (score 15):

You can use [csvsql](http://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/scripts/csvsql.html), which is part of `csvkit` (a suite of utilities for converting to and working with CSV files):

- Linux or Mac OS X
- free and open source
- `sudo pip install csvkit`
- Example:  `csvsql --dialect mysql --snifflimit 100000 datatwithheaders.csv > mytabledef.sql`
- It creates a `CREATE TABLE` statement based on the file content. Column names are taken from the first line of the CSV file.

---

To extend on [ivansabik](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/120583/ivansabik)'s [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/168347/9622) using `pandas`, see [How to insert pandas dataframe via mysqldb into database?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48393139/395857).

Comment: csvsql is too slow for a reasonably large file. In my case, a 7.8M csv file takes 4+ minutes to finish.

Answer (score 3):

If you're ok with using Python, Pandas worked great for me (csvsql hanged forever and less cols and rows than in your case). Something like:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/PATH/TO/FILE.csv', sep='|')
# Optional, set your indexes to get Primary Keys
df = df.set_index(['COL A', 'COL B'])

engine = create_engine('mysql://user:pass@host/db', echo=False)

df.to_sql(table_name, engine, index=False)
```

Comment: Where do you define `dwh_engine`? Is this a typo and you meant `engine`?

Comment: Yes it should be `engine`! Corrected the answer thanks for spotting

Comment: to_sql takes up too much time if the number of rows is high. For us, around 36000 rows took around 90 mins. A direct load statement was done in 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a CREATE TABLE based on datatypes, size, etc of the various columns.

Then you use LOAD DATA INFILE ... FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"  SKIP 1 LINE ...;  (See the manual page for details.)

Do likewise for each csv --> table.